# Converting mortise lock to cylindrical

Tags: doors, lock, mortise

I am trying to convert an older style lock to a modern one. Turns out I can just reuse the mortise mechanism but unfortunately it won't support the privacy pin, so I am looking to replace that too.

Here's a photo of my door...the round mechanism just about fits (I could probably force it in), but what to do about the gap? Would it be better to try and add some wood, then fill in everything with wood filler and drill a new hole? Or better to try and install the new mechanism and fill the wood filler around it? Or another way?

This seems like a somewhat straightforward job but want to make sure there aren't any gotchas..

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to use a mortise-style lock for the new lock? Mortise locks are still made to this day (i.e. it's not like the form factor has become completely obsolete), but you may need to shop at a local locksmith to find a suitable lockset for your application.

Comment: The dimensions are non standard so it's really just hard to find an option which I like aesthetically which also fits.